# Finding the equation of locus

Tags: analytic-geometry

The co ordinates of any position of a moving point P are given by

$$\left[\frac{(7t-2)}{(3t+2)} , \frac{(4t+5)}{(t-1)}\right]$$

where $t$ is a variable parameter.Find the equation of locus of $P$.

I could not understand the question especially saying what is a variable parameter.
 So please solve the question explaining the meaning of variable parameter

Comment: You want to know how to solve this or the meaning of a variable parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say the co-ordinates of a point P is given by $(h,k)$. Then by the problem, $$h=\frac{7t-2}{3t+2}$$ $$k=\frac{4t+5}{t-1}$$ On simplification they give
$$t=\frac{2+2h}{7-3h}$$ $$t=\frac{k+5}{k-4}$$

So required locus is $$\frac{2+2h}{7-3h}=\frac{k+5}{k-4}$$ i.e. $$\frac{2+2x}{7-3x}=\frac{y+5}{y-4}$$

Simplify to get your answer.

As for variable parameter, it is a something on which $x$ and $y$ depend, as you can see. So it is more fundamental. You might want to read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameter).

Comment: The answer above coincides with what i have got.

Comment: @Adelafif Congrats..